# What are these types of connectors called?

Tags: connector, identification, breadboard

Not only am I curious of the name. I would like to know what parts I would need to go from breadboard to this type of a connector. I have connectors in varying pin counts.

[image: connectors]

Comment: Please measure the distance between the two end pins of the left connector, divide by 5 and provide that number. Pin pitch is an important factor in figuring out connector type.

Comment: @Daniel looks to be 2.54mm pitch

Comment: I like measurements, not guesses

Comment: if you can't measure easily, put a ruler next to it and take another photo.

Answer (score 4):

As @Daniel said, make the appropriate measurement. If you confirm those have 2mm pitch, then they definitely are JST connectors, PH series ([datahseet](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf)), or some compatible copy from another manufacturer.

Those JST connectors are very widely used on consumer products. However, they are not so widely known to hobbyists. And actually, a lot of "please identify this connector" questions end up being JST connectors.

Now, using those on a breadboard is tricky because of the 2mm pitch (which is maybe why they are not used much by hobbyists). Breadboards typically use 2.54 pitch, so you can't plug those connectors directly. You could however solder wires to the pin tails (if your hands are steady enough) and connect these wires to the breadboard.

Comment: I'll try to find a decent ruler and measure.